# FileFormatException loading tons of BitmapImages

Tags: c#, wpf, jpeg

I am programming in C# and WPF and trying to load tons of images, but after about **5 seconds** I'm getting Exceptions, which are not thrown directly (Visual Studio doesn't stop the program) and are logged as catched in Visual Studio.

My code looks like this:

```
    public Dictionary<string, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage> images { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        images = new Dictionary<string, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\path\to\thumbnails"))
        {
            string id = Path.GetFileName(file);
            id = id.Substring(0, id.Length - 4);

            var image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(file));
            image.Freeze();

            images.Add(id, image);
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

There are more than **8k jpg** pictures in the folder, which are **44 x 64** pixels big. When running the program I see the Memory usage in Visual Studio and if there was an Exception. As mentioned before, the first 5 seconds or so are fine, but then I am getting an Exception with catch for every following picture I think. It's hard to tell because they are thrown too fast and Visual Studio displays them too slow, so they pop up in packs.

When the Exceptions start to show up, the Memory usage is rising very slowly compared to before, but if I let the program finish the loading all pictures can be displayed without problems. It also looks like Visual Studio is overwhelmed by the amount of Exceptions causing the Logger to be slower than real time. 1 second in Visual Studio seems to become 6 real time seconds and it's taking more than a minute of these "fake" seconds.

The Exception is the following (I am from Germany):

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst: 'System.IO.FileFormatException' in PresentationCore.dll ("Der Bitmap-Farbkontext ist ungültig.")
```

It looks like the picture is corrupted or has some errors, but I wasn't able to retrieve a filename and when I was, I tested the file seperately and it was okay.

I am just looking for a way to load all the images in normal speed.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**
Somehow I disabled the "Just My Code" option in Visual Studio, causing to show exceptions outside my code and slowing Visual Studio down. Now it is running as fast as in the modification mentioned in the comments and takes about a minute to load all images.

I'm still wondering, if there is a way to load the images faster. All I am doing with them is displaying them.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the process in the foreach in a try...catch?

Comment: if there is an error, it might take times longer than what you expected. I would store the list of "definitely working" file paths first as fast as possible, then show them one by one with your "normal" speed later. Like Jonathan said, use try catch and collect the "non-working" files into a list to debug later on.

Comment: When I put the process in the foreach in a try and catch it doesn't change anything. The program never enters the catch block, but exceptions are still logged. I tried changing the program, so that it doesn't add the images to a dictionary but instead replaces one BitmapImage variable for each image. That works just fine and takes 1 minute and 18 seconds. So the problem could be, that the dictionary is getting too big?

Comment: I tried pinpointing the amount of "working" images by counting and breaking out of the foreach at different values. It seems to happen at 1010 - 1020 images, but it is not always the same result for different runs. Since Directory.GetFiles should always return the same List it appears that one image could work one time and the other not. Memory usage is at that point at about 340 MB.